# He rares himself up?

Tags: word-choice

*Raring* definition: very enthusiastic and eager to do something.

I want to use *rares*, as in:

> He rares himself up, ready to tell her.

I'm wanting to use it as in the cited example, meaning he gears himself up, sort of like an instant pep-talk, like readying himself. But it looks as though *rares* isn't a word for what I need it for.

Can I use it like this or not?

Comment: Are you sure it's not "rears up".  This is what a horse does when it raises it's front legs off the ground, and it's sometimes used to describe a person who stands tall in a sort of menacing stance.

Comment: @Hot Licks: yes and no. From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rare): rare (v) "rise up," 1833, dialectal variant of *rear* (v.1). Sense of "eager" (in *raring to go*) first recorded 1909. Related: Rared; raring.

Comment: @PeterShor - I've never really heard that sense of "rare" except in the set phrase "raring to go".  It would not be recognized by many US English speakers in any other phrasing.

Comment: @Hot Licks: neither have I. Somehow the dialectical pronunciation of *rear* made its way into the standard language in that one phrase. However, if I search *"rared up"* in Google Books, it comes up pretty often. But almost always, it seems, as a dialectical pronunciation of *"reared up"* and not in the sense the OP wants.

Comment: caio, perhaps you should edit your question to describe more extensively what meaning you're looking for.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help - I may just have to use "gears himself up", as this alternative has just popped into mind. Ciao :)

Comment: "Rare up and ready to go" is a phrase I have heard often enough growing up.

Answer (score 8):

You might consider ***psychs*** *himself up*

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/psych+up) defines it as:

> *Inf.*  to get someone excited or mentally prepared for something. *I psyched myself up to sing in front of all those people. The coach psyched up the team for the game.*

and

> ***psych somebody up*** - to make someone enthusiastic about something they will do *[...] Tim was psyching himself up to run the 26.2-mile course.*

Answer (score 3):

Well,

> **rare** chiefly dialectal variant of *rear*

---

> **rear** verb transitive verb
>
> 2
>
> c \ˈrir\ (audio pronunciation) *dialectal, chiefly England* :  **to stir
>   up to action :  arouse**
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

thus in principle one could say

"rare myself up" to mean "arouse myself [to enthusiasm, etc]"

Problem is: it's not there, it's not idiomatic, as others (Peter Shor and  Hot Licks) have observed already.

It's used only as "to rise to his full height," like a lion/horse does, on its hind legs.

> [An Ocean Free Lance: A Novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Ei87AQAAMAAJ&q=%22rearing%20himself%20to%22&dq=%22rearing%20himself%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b3AXVZizGcK1sQTBsYL4Dw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBDgK) - Page 280 William Clark Russell - 1896
>
> ... and **rearing himself to his full height**, he thundered out in a
>   voice positively hoarse with passion; “How dare you order a delicate
>   boy like him into that dark rigging?”

I'd suggest instead:

**"/hustle/hurry/rush/push/drive/compel/bestir/rouse/arouse/commove/agitate,/excite/ himself to excitement/enthusiasm"**

or the common

**"pump himself up"**

Answer (score 1):

You can use it similar to this, though usually one would say "He got himself all rared up." This is still common usage in the American South/Southwest, though it would be considered more odd in other parts of the country, so consider using it if the character you're writing for is either older or Southern, and consider other terms if they aren't.  "Psyched himself up" would be something a young person would say.

Answer (score -1):

It's idiomatic, to the point of sounding like a cliche:

> He **reared** himself up, ready to tell her.

Upon reaching the decision that they must preform an action they are not emotionally comfortable with, human beings might physically rear themselves to their full height to aid in mentally preparing for the ordeal. Usually with a sharp intake of breath and a 'Gaa, *alright*'. You don't *rare* yourself up for a confrontation you don't want to have; you *steel* yourself and put your game face on.